# MethodInvoker for a button

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Now i use a method that update all the time when connection event is raised, but now for connection i use a different thread an i have problem to call that event from Icommand thread i get an error System.StackOwverflowException, i read on internet bout this problem and this problem i think cam solved with Invoker but i do not understand the concept of invoker how to use it.

My code:

```
 public class NewMeasurementCommand : ICommand
    {

        private MeasurementViewModel measurementViewModel = null;
        private BaseViewModel baseViewModel;
        private GpfGateway gpfGateway;

        public NewMeasurementCommand(MeasurementViewModel viewModel)
        {

            measurementViewModel = viewModel;
            GpfGateway.GetInstance().SystemStatus += updateCanExecuteChanged;

        }
        /// <summary>Notifies command to update CanExecute property.</summary>
        private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateCanExecuteChanged(sender, new EventArgs());
        }
        bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
        {

            return GpfGateway.GetInstance().IsConnected;

        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
        {
            NewMeasurementViewModel newMeasurementViewModel = new NewMeasurementViewModel();
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.MeasurementStep = new MeasurementInfoStep();
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.MeasurementStep.NewMeasurementVM = newMeasurementViewModel;
            GpfGateway.GetInstance().ControllerValuesArrived += measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.MeasurementStep.RemoteControllerArrived;
            newMeasurementViewModel.MeasurementModel = measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel;
            newMeasurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.CurrentMeasurement = new Measurement();
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.MeasurementStep.CurrentMeasurement = newMeasurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.CurrentMeasurement;
            newMeasurementViewModel.NavigationResolver = measurementViewModel.NavigationResolver;
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.CurrentMeasurement = new Measurement();
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.MeasurementStep.CurrentMeasurement = measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.CurrentMeasurement;
            measurementViewModel.MeasurementModel.CurrentMeasurement.Tester = Environment.UserName;
            measurementViewModel.NavigationResolver.GoToMeasurementInfoStep(newMeasurementViewModel);
        }
       private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());
        }
}
}
```

What I try to make:

```
 public delegate void InvokeDelegate();

       private void EnabledChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                EnabledChanged();
            });



                if(sender == gpfGateway.IsConnected);
        }
```

If anyone have some advice it will be very helpful.

Comment: This is where you have problem:        private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            updateCanExecuteChanged(sender, new EventArgs());
        } that method recurrently executes itself until you hit stack overflow.

Comment: [Invoker](http://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/dota2.gamepedia.com/5/59/Invo_cast_01.mp3). Try this one> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting a stack overflow because your EnabledChanged function calls itself. So its just going round and round recalling itself until it goes boom.

If you look at [Microsofts invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

You'll see they dont call the function from itself, but from somewhere else.

What you can do is something like this

```
private void UpdateStatus(String message)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            UpdateStatus(message);
        });
    else
        label1.Text = message;
}
```

While this is setting text on a label, its still a reasonable example. Any GUI element cannot be played with from another thread, so, you can use a function such as this from anywhere, if it needs to it then invokes the command. You can have it call itself, in this instance, because after invoking it wont need to invoke itself again.

Comment: i have try this method but I think i need to use a lib for Invoke because my compiler don not recognize tenth method. Any idea why not recognize that method?

Comment: `private void updateCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if (this.InvokeRequired)
               this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
               {
                   updateCanExecuteChanged(sender, new EventArgs());
               });
            else
               CanExecuteChanged(this, new EventArgs());

       }